# AWS API Gateway - REST calls - Costs when CORS fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

On AWS official [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/pricing/?nc1=h_ls) it is written:

> For HTTP APIs and REST APIs, you pay only for the API calls you
> receive and the amount of data transferred out.

Do I also have to pay if CORS is enabled and the request comes from another origin?

Thus, can I use CORS as kind of a free restriction rule and reject the request because of CORS reasons? How could I do that?

Comment: You pay for that, yes. E.g. for GET requests the request will be handled entirely by the server, only the browser will then reject the response if the CORS headers don't match. For preflight requests you pay for the OPTIONS request. And non browser requests generally don't have an origin at all.

Comment: Ok thanks, so for non browser requests with no origin, the request will still be handled by the api gateway and it returns a valid response?

Comment: Of course, the server does generally not reject any requests for CORS reasons, CORS is a feature for browsers and browsers decide which request to block or let through. And browsers are the only things that send a meaningful origin.

Comment: ok, so its also absolutely not possible to reject because of CORS reasons?

Comment: You probably could but that is not what CORS is for.